# Java : smiley face

Tags: java, graphics

[image: Smiley Face]

I want to know what i should use to draw the mouth and eyes of the above smiley face. so far i managed to draw whats behind the eyes and mouth (Look down for the result so far). i tried using Arc2D.double as you can see in the code down marked as a comment.

Here is what i made so far:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class draw2 extends JPanel
{
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    this.setBackground(new Color( 255,255,255));

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(100,100,300,300);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillArc(110,120,250,250,90,180);

    g.setColor(new Color (218,165,32));
    g.drawArc(130,110,250,280,90,-180);

    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(125,105,250,290);

   // draw Arc2D.Double
    //g2.setColor(Color.black);
    //g2.fill(new Arc2D.Double(130, 200, 200,150,170, 200, Arc2D.OPEN));


}


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Task 2");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        draw2 d = new draw2();
        f.add(d);
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

RESULT SO FAR:

[image]

Comment: nice try and mvce so far.... :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Thank you but i am stuck now.

Comment: don't worry, somebody will guide you in right direction, I've checked Arch2D and seems a good approach... but I'm almost backend dev... graphs are not my best skill

Comment: updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe you could use a filled [Path2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html).

Comment: @JordiCastilla It looks so much better Thank youu!

Answer (score 1):

A starting point for the left and right laugh lines might be following snippet.

```
BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(
        12,
        BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
        0,
        BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL
);
g2.setStroke(stroke);

GeneralPath leftLaughLine = new GeneralPath();
int x = 150;
int y = 230;
leftLaughLine.moveTo(x, y);
leftLaughLine.curveTo(x - 20, y + 5, x - 25, y + 25, x - 25, y + 25);
g2.draw(leftLaughLine);

GeneralPath rigthLaughLine = new GeneralPath();
x = 350;
y = 230;
rigthLaughLine.moveTo(x, y);
rigthLaughLine.curveTo(x + 20, y + 5, x + 25, y + 25, x + 25, y + 25);
g2.draw(rigthLaughLine);
```

[image]